# Deaths per confirmed cases vs Deaths per population?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, epidemiology

Recently, in a popular interview to President Trump:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zaaTZkqsaxY

there was a discussion about the interpretation and relevance of:

1. Number of deaths per confirmed cases of covid
2. Number of deaths per population.

Some outlets simply report both:

https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/data/mortality

There is a debate about which one should be used but I feel that the interpretation of these concepts can be quite different.

**Question:** What is the interpretation of these concepts and is there a preference for using any of these two summaries?

**Disclaimer**: I want to focus on the interpretation and differences of these concepts for my own understanding of descriptive statistics reported by international outlets, rather than the political aspects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, dealths per capita of population is preferable to deaths per capita of confirmed cases. The reason for this is quite simple. In the latter, the denominator, number of confirmed cases depends very much on the extent, and accuracy of, testing, whereas in the former, the total population is well known.

It is also worth noting that the numerator in both cases, number of deaths, is somewhat problematic due to the issue of people who died *from* covid and people who dies *with* covid. In many cases covid is not the direct cause of death, but it nevertheless leads to death. For this reason a better numerator is *excess deaths* which is, roughly speaking the number of deaths in excess of what would be expected over the same period of time.

Comment: Deaths per confirmed case could be seen as a measure of health service performance. If it is low you are intervening well with cases. But there are many other variables as you mention in your second paragraph.

Comment: @mdewey Good point, but if deaths per confirned case is low that could be either because  treatments have been sucessful, or because testing has been extensive; while if it is high that could reflect fewer tests being carried out (eg in the UK before testing was ramped up) or that treatments have been poor. I can see why certain politicians would like this statistic ;)